# How do I change my domain name?

Tags: wordpress, domain-name

I have "info" at the beginning of my website url. I want to change it to something else. Is there a hassle free way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

'info' Is a short form for information, that is used to set and email address of the website owner e.g info@domain.com, The only thing to do for you to eliminate that 'info', is you acquiring a domain such as www.*domain*.com and then hosting your website alternatively you can get a sub domain from anybody that is offering you.

Comment: Thanks Job, What I'm wondering about is will I be able to use my existing content under the new domain. Can that be easily done?

Comment: let me know some staffs from you, have already designed your site? and if so on which directory in the Cpanel have you placed your content?

Comment: Yes I've been working on it a few weeks. It's Wordpress hosted by Bluehost I think. I'm not exactly sure where my content lives on the site. Each blog post has a permalink and they're not listed as pages.

Comment: If that is the case, I advice you to find a new domain probably from them, they will transfer for content safely, you dont have to be worried, your content is safe, Just pay for the domain and let your content be online.

Comment: That certainly sounds hassle free. That suits me. Thanks.

Comment: You can vote up the answer. That's my humble request. welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what do you mean about "info in the beginning".
Is it info.website.com or www.infowebsite.com? If it is the first you can redirect it to newsubdomain.website.com or just to www.website.com.
If you mean that your domain name is www.infowebsite.com you should buy a new domain to do the thing.
Give more details about your question and we will give you the right answer.

Comment: Hey Kas, it's www.infodomain.com

Answer (score 0):

You have said that your domain is www.infodomain.com, my advice to you is there is no shortcut to that, you just have to buy a new domain because this is a domain on its on, you need to search for a new one and probably purchase, if you need to redirect from your current domain to the new bought domain then you can also let us know.

Comment: Thanks Job for taking time to answer my question

Comment: If it has helped you somehow ,you can vote up that answer, all apreciate.

Answer (score 0):

solution is you need to purchase a New domain for that . and In your old domain's root folder you need to create a .htacess file and need to insert the following code .

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

all the request on old domains will redirect to new one . And you need to upload the content on new domain

2) There are some hosting provide which can use other Ip address to pick the content in this way you don't need to upload content on new server. Just will the IP address of old domain and there will be a new domain with the content from your old domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the domain name then you can delete the domain name within 3days after registration and you will get the refund and register the New required domain name.

Or If you want to change the domain name after some days of registration then there is only one way that you have to buy new Domain.